# Global Variables Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I am working on a project for school where I have to create a quiz using javascript. Now, I've already made one before and it worked fine, but now i tried the same code in my new quiz and there are some issues with global variables.

I have a small fragment of my code here which already gives some issues:

```js
let list = [
            'https://imgur.com/8aYvbBg.png',
            'https://imgur.com/9ZDQazn.png',
            'https://i.imgur.com/kbeMNq5.png',
            'https://i.imgur.com/9w8sLx2.png',
            'https://imgur.com/u34JvAy.png',
            'https://imgur.com/SewCLFu.png'
          ];
          
let guess;

function choosePicture() {
          
   /* We choose a random dish from the dishList
      and display it at the #headerDish position */
      
   let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
   guess = list[rand];
   
   $("#headerPic").attr('src', guess);
   
   //chooseAnswers(guess);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="headerPic" width="100px" />

<button onclick="choosePicture()">Choose</button>
```

This does not correctly display the #headerPic in the correct place in my html document. However, once I move the lets list and guess inside the function like this:

```
function choosePic() {
  let list = [
    'https://imgur.com/8aYvbBg.png',
    'https://imgur.com/9ZDQazn.png',
    'https://i.imgur.com/kbeMNq5.png',
    'https://i.imgur.com/9w8sLx2.png',
    'https://imgur.com/u34JvAy.png',
    'https://imgur.com/SewCLFu.png'
  ];
  /* We choose a random dish from the dishList
  and display it at the #headerDish position */
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  let guess = list[rand];
  $("#headerPic").attr('src', guess);
}
```

all works well... I need some global variable to keep track of this headerPic because that is the thing that is going to be guessed, but my code doesn't seem to function with any global variables inside the functions.

Comment: `let` has a block scope. so I think what is happening is that in the scenario 1, list.length gives error because you are accessing the list variable defined in different scope. Try defining list with var in scenario 1. and it will work fine.

Comment: @loki: JS is lexically scoped, so the function can read variables in the enclosing scope. Block scoping doesn't change this.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, you haven't included it in the question. Post a full, working example of the problem.

Comment: Edited to show that the code provided by the OP does work... Looks delicious :)